# How to show an 'Update' button below TextFormField when i click on 'edit' button in ListTile in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-list-tile

This is some of the code for UI. My requirement is to add an Update button below textFormField when the user clicks on edit button in the ListTile. I am able to pass name and age data from database to TextFormField. But how do i bring up an update button in UI on clicking edit button?

```
class ScreenHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenHome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getAllStudents();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          AddStudentWidget(),
          const Expanded(child: ListStudentWidget())
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}


TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();

class AddStudentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddStudentWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: nameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Name',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: ageController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Age',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  onAddStudentButtonClicked();
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                label: const Text('Add Student'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


class ListStudentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListStudentWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: studentListNotifier,
      builder:
          (BuildContext ctx, List<StudentModel> studentList, Widget? child) {
        return ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              final data = studentList[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data.name),
                subtitle: Text(data.age),
                trailing: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        deleteStudent(data.id!);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        editStudent(data.id!);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return const Divider(
                thickness: 2,
              );
            },
            itemCount: studentList.length);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[This is my expected output. When i click on edit button, a new update button needs to appear below textfield. Any leads would be greatly appreciated. Thanks you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8oJ1.png)

Comment: 1. Create a stateful widget with a `Row` that contains your controls (such as the add student button). 2. Inside its `children` list, add the update button. 3. In order to show/hide it, keep a flag indicating whether you are currently editing a student, and use that flag to add or remove the edit button: `children: [if (isEditing) UpdateStudentButton(), AddStudentButton()]`